# Hydration In Nextjs 13.4 using redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I am using Nextjs 13.4 and redux-toolkit in my project
what I am trying to do here is to filter the data based on the selected value

what I did is to create the store as shown below

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import searchDataReducer from "./features/SearchSlice";
import { homeProductsApi } from "./api/apiSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [homeProductsApi.reducerPath]: homeProductsApi.reducer,
    searchData: searchDataReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    return getDefaultMiddleware().concat(homeProductsApi.middleware);
  },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

And create the apiSlice.ts as shown below

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const homeProductsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "homeProductsApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "https://fakestoreapi.com/" }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getAll: builder.query<Product[], null>({
        query: () => 'products'
    }),
    getCategory: builder.query<Product[], string>({
      query: (selectedValue) => `products/category/${selectedValue}`,
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetCategoryQuery, useGetAllQuery } = homeProductsApi;
```

In the Home page I used the client rendering way and the data was fetched succesfully but then I tried to use the server rendering as shown below

```
import Product from "@/components/Product";
import SearchForm from "@/components/SearchForm";
import { store } from "@/store";

export const metadata = {
  title: "Home",
  description: "Check the best deals from our store",
};

export default async function Home() {
  const response = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
  const products: Product[] = await response.json();

  const searchData = store.getState().searchData.value;

  return (
    <main className="min-h-screen max-w-7xl mx-auto px-8 xl:px-0 mt-48">
      <section className="flex flex-col space-y-12 pb-44">
        <SearchForm />
        <h1 className="text-2xl sm:text-3xl md:text-5xl font-bold text-center">
          DEALS OF THE DAY
        </h1>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-y-10 gap-x-6 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 xl:gap-x-8">
          {searchData.length > 0
            ? searchData.map((searchProduct: Product) => (
                <Product key={searchProduct.id} product={searchProduct} />
              ))
            : products?.map((product) => (
                <Product key={product.id} product={product} />
              ))}
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}
```

I have tried to do that based on [Jack Herrington](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRLjoT4r-jc&t=744s&ab_channel=JackHerrington) video, but I got an error with hydration.

I'll be grateful for any help. Thanks.